# Why Fast Fourier Convolution does not work in set parameter : ratio_gin and ratio_gout:0.5?

Tags: image, pytorch, fft, torch

I am studying about the Fourier Transform and Fast Fourier Convolution.

I would like to use FFC but having trouble getting it to work.

#### Fast Fourier Convolution

Fast Fourier Convolution NeurIPS 2020
original implementation https://github.com/pkumivision/FFC/blob/main/model_zoo/ffc.py

paper https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2020/file/2fd5d41ec6cfab47e32164d5624269b1-Paper.pdf

[image]

[image]

**The above imgs refer to pages 3 and 4 of the paper**

##FFC code is
reference:
https://github.com/pkumivision/FFC/blob/main/model_zoo/ffc.py

```py
class FFC(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size,
                 ratio_gin, ratio_gout, stride=1, padding=0,
                 dilation=1, groups=1, bias=False, enable_lfu=True):
        super(FFC, self).__init__()

        assert stride == 1 or stride == 2, "Stride should be 1 or 2."
        self.stride = stride

        in_cg = int(in_channels * ratio_gin)
        in_cl = in_channels - in_cg
        out_cg = int(out_channels * ratio_gout)
        out_cl = out_channels - out_cg
        #groups_g = 1 if groups == 1 else int(groups * ratio_gout)
        #groups_l = 1 if groups == 1 else groups - groups_g

        self.ratio_gin = ratio_gin
        self.ratio_gout = ratio_gout

        module = nn.Identity if in_cl == 0 or out_cl == 0 else nn.Conv2d
        self.convl2l = module(in_cl, out_cl, kernel_size,
                              stride, padding, dilation, groups, bias)
        module = nn.Identity if in_cl == 0 or out_cg == 0 else nn.Conv2d
        self.convl2g = module(in_cl, out_cg, kernel_size,
                              stride, padding, dilation, groups, bias)
        module = nn.Identity if in_cg == 0 or out_cl == 0 else nn.Conv2d
        self.convg2l = module(in_cg, out_cl, kernel_size,
                              stride, padding, dilation, groups, bias)
        module = nn.Identity if in_cg == 0 or out_cg == 0 else SpectralTransform
        self.convg2g = module(
            in_cg, out_cg, stride, 1 if groups == 1 else groups // 2, enable_lfu)

    def forward(self, x):
        x_l, x_g = x if type(x) is tuple else (x, 0)
        out_xl, out_xg = 0, 0

        if self.ratio_gout != 1:
            out_xl = self.convl2l(x_l) + self.convg2l(x_g)
        if self.ratio_gout != 0:
            out_xg = self.convl2g(x_l) + self.convg2g(x_g)

        return out_xl, out_xg
```

Below is my test code using this above .py file.

If ratio_gout is set to 0.5 each as 　α parameter in the paper, it will result in ERROR.

```py
#1.gray schale:

ffc_m=FFC(in_channels=1,out_channels=10,kernel_size=1,
         ratio_gin=0.5,ratio_gout=0.5,padding="same",groups=1)

#gray schale sample
gray_img=torch.randn(1,1,32,32).float()

out1,out2=ffc_m(temp_img)
print(out1.shape)
print(out2.shape)

#>>>torch.Size([1, 5, 32, 32])
#>>>torch.Size([1, 5, 32, 32])

2.like RGB schale :
ffc_m=FFC(in_channels=3,out_channels=10,kernel_size=1,
         ratio_gin=0.5,ratio_gout=0.5,padding="same",groups=1)

#3channels
temp_img=torch.randn(1,3,32,32).float()

out=ffc_m(temp_img)
#>>>output error is below
#RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [5, 2, 1, 1], expected input[1, 3, 32, 32] to have 2 channels, but got 3 channels instead

#but works for the following parameters: ratio_gin=0. ratio_gout=1
ffc_m=FFC(in_channels=3,out_channels=10,kernel_size=1,
         ratio_gin=0,ratio_gout=1.,padding="same",groups=1)

temp_img=torch.randn(1,3,32,32).float()
out1,out2=ffc_m(temp_img)
#out1:0.
#out2.shape:torch.Size([1, 10, 32, 32])
```

I just couldn't figure out Why this FFC module does not work for 3 channel img tensor with ratio_gin:0.5 and ratio_gout:0.5 each parameter.

The parameter of [αin,αout] in this reference is not equal　 FFC module`s ratio_gin and ratio_gout?

Sorry for the confusing explanation.

I would appreciate any advice you could give me. Best regards.Thank you.

Comment: You haven't really described the problem - in what way exactly does it "not work properly" ?

Comment: Also, where is this `FCC` function from? Please include complete, runnable code, with all its import statements, so we know what you are doing and can reproduce your results. See [mre].